# Ignore parent padding with variable width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button inside a div which is inside a div and I am trying to have the button in and inner div ignore the parent divs padding here is my code

```
<div style="padding:10px; background:red;">
    <div style="width:100%; margin:-10px;">

      <button style="background:blue; width:100%">
        Some test text
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can be seen in fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5sc5y4z3/.

setting the `margin:-10px` works on the leftside but then, the button is `20px` short on the right side.

How can I extend it so it fills the whole width of the parent div?

Thanks

Comment: Why not remove the `padding` for that specific container then? BTW If you can't use `calc()` then it's also possible to ignore a parent's padding by applying `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` to the child.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

100% width doesn't include the negative margins. You need to add it back:

```
<div style="width:calc(100%+20px); margin:-10px;">
```

[CSS `calc()` is supported in all modern browsers since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), so it's safe to use in most web development projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

HTML:

```
<div style="padding:10px; background:red;">
    <div style="width:100%;background-color:lime">

      <button style="background:blue; width:100%">
        Some test text
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's getting clipped, so you could also use the following to mask the right side:

**HTML**

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin:-10px;">
```